# Reference to a non-shared member threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, addressof

I have opened a project built with VS2010 in VS2017.

The code hasn't changed and the 2010 version built perfectly but when building with 2017 I get a 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference' error with the following code.

```
Dim doCheck As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Check_Form.checkList)
doCheck.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
doCheck.Start(thisname & "~" & thisnum)
```

The 'AddressOf' part throws the error.

Has something changed in VS2017 or have I forgotten to amend something? It's been a while since I looked at this but I've got a new signing certificate and the System.Threading is imported as always.

The Check_Form.checkList sub is public but not shared but it never has been in the past and always ran ok.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Check_Form` a variable/property or a type?  Are you trying to refer to a method of a default instance there?

Comment: sry - been offline for a few days. Check_Form is another windows form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Check_Form is type of that owner form. And therefore `My.Forms.Check_Form.checkList` was used with implicit call of `Check_Form.checkList`

I'm not sure if version 2017 has some changes in reference priorities but try changing your code to

```
Dim doCheck As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf My.Forms.Check_Form.checkList)
```

to get explicit version of the same code. Current version might prefere type before My.Forms property.